# how to send selected data item from firebase recycle view to the recycle view of different activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

i am creating a meeting schedule android app in which a "meeting schedule activity" have a filed as "add attendees" and when it is clicked a list of all users will be shown in recycle view and User should be able to select some of Users from the all users listed in recycle.[the feature which want to add my app is mention in this pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MjL2k.png)

**my question is how to make multiple selection from recycle view (listOfUser activity) and how send those selected data item to the another recycle view of different activity (schedule activity) **

i am adding code of adpter,main activity,view holder classes

**main activity(ListOfUsersActivity.java)
**

```
package com.example.firebaseapplication;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ListOfUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rcv;
    myAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_of_user);
        setTitle("List of Register Users");

        rcv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rclView);
        rcv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options =
                new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Model>()
                        .setQuery(FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Registered Users"), Model.class)
                        .build();

        adapter = new myAdapter(options);
        rcv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        adapter.startListening();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
    }
```

**Adepter (myAdepter.java)**

```
package com.example.firebaseapplication;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class myAdapter extends FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Model,myViewHolder> {

    public myAdapter(FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Model> options) {
        super(options);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row_layout,parent,false);

        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Model model) {
    holder.textViewName.setText(model.getName());
    holder.textViewDepartment.setText(model.getDepartment());
    Glide.with(holder.img.getContext()).load(model.getPurl()).into(holder.img);
    }

}
```

**ViewHolder(myViewholder.java)**

```
package com.example.firebaseapplication;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;


public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
     CircleImageView img;;
    TextView textViewName,textViewDepartment;
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        img = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_row_layout_img1);
        textViewName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_row_layout_t1);
        textViewDepartment = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.single_row_layout_t2);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar thing. I have added a check box for each item in the first activity RecyclerView. The user can check those thems whose details he wants to send to the next activity. The data can be sent to the next activity as an array of models(class) along with the intent. I shared my code with someone just yesterday. You can refer to the same answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76075368/5362509